# Анимация нажатия на элемент recyclerview

Tags: android, listview, recyclerview

Как сделать эффект нажатия на элемент `recyclerview` как в `listview`?

Answer (score 4):

Добавьте это свойство в корневой  Layout вашего макета используемого для элементов RecycleView

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Например так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Только лучше без android вроде как. Просто ?attr/selectableItemBackground